# Disabling iPhone keyboard for textarea in web application

Tags: iphone, mobile, safari, keyboard, textarea

So I have multiple textareas on my page that are editable depending on a users status.  The problem is that even when a user clicks on a textarea that they are not allowed to edit, the keyboard comes up on mobile safari.  The user can't actually edit the textarea, but it's really annoying/looks bad.  I was thinking of maybe making it disabled but without actually changing it's look.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using TextView or TextField? For a TextView you can set Editable to NO to prevent the keyboard being popped up.

For TextField I guess you can set userInteractionEnabled to NO. Haven't tried this before though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the input/textarea field?  I think if you click on that the keyboard says closed.

```
<index disabled />
```

or

```
<textarea disabled />
```